# Identificar si un número es primo o no en C

Tags: c

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>


int main()
{
    int num;
    printf ("Ingresa un numero\n");
    scanf("%d",&num);

    int div;
    bool sino;

    if (num <= 1) {
        printf("\nNo es primo\n");
    } else {
        for (int i = 2; i <= num / 2; i++) {
            div = num % i;
            if (div == 0) {
                sino = 0;
            } else {
                sino = 1;
            }
        }

        if (sino == 0) {
            printf("No es primo");
        } else {
            printf("Es primo");
        }
    }
}
```

Tengo duda de porque el código no funciona, se supone que tiene que identificar los números primos pero solo identifica cual es par y cual es impar, ¿Qué podría cambiar o agregar?

Comment: Revisa el for. Date cuenta que si encuentras un número en el que el resto de dividir te da 0, en ese momento sabes que es primo, y tienes que salir del bucle.

Comment: ¡Gracias a todos!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema surge de que no interrumpes el bucle de comprobación una vez has averiguado que el número tiene algún divisor; así que sigue comprobando y se queda con el último resultado, por ejemplo, en el caso de introducir `6`:

1. Primera vuelta del bucle: `6 % 2` es cero, no es primo. Aquí debería finalizar el proceso de comprovación pero sigues.
2. Segunda vuelta del bucle: `6 % 3` es cero, no es primo. Ni siquiera deberíamos haber llegado aquí.
3. Tercera vuelta del bucle: `6 % 4` es dos ¿es un candidato a primo?

Prueba a hacer algo así:

```
int num;
printf ("Ingresa un numero\n");
scanf("%d",&num);

for (int divisor = 2; divisor < num / 2; ++divisor)
    if (!(num % divisor))
    {
        printf("No es primo\n");
        return 0; // Si no es primo, dejamos de buscar.
    }

// Si llegamos aquí, es que no era divisible entre nada: será primo
printf("Es primo\n");
return 0;
```

Answer (score 3):

```
    for (int i = 2; i <= num / 2; i++) {
        div = num % i;
        if (div == 0) {
            sino = 0;
        } else {
            sino = 1;
        }
    }
```

Un número deja de ser primo en el mismo momento en el que encuentras un divisor. En ese momento puedes parar de buscar ... tu no haces eso, tu sigues iterando y te quedas, exclusivamente, con el resultado de la última división.

- si el número es impar, el último número que compruebas es `(i-1)/2`. Este número no va a ser nunca un divisor natural del número, luego `sino` valdrá 1.
- Si el número es par, el último número que compruebas es `i/2`, está claro que este número va a ser un divisor, luego `sino` valdrá 0.

Lo que necesitas debería parecerse más bien al siguiente código:

```
    for (int i = 2; i <= num / 2; i++) {
        div = num % i;
        if (div == 0) {
            sino = 0;
            break;
        }
    }
```

Es decir, cuando encuentras un divisor marcas el resultado correspondiente y dejas de iterar.

Ahora bien, para que esto funcione el 100% de las veces es necesario que inicialices `sino`:

```
bool sino = true;
```

Así evitas que, por cosas del destino, te de por comprobar un número primo y el algoritmo te acabe diciendo que no lo es. Si no inicializas la variable, la misma tendrá un valor aleatorio y existe una probabilidad entre 2^32 de que sea 0. Cosas más raras se han visto